# Requiring gems in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm having an issue with Geocoder in Rails: specifically that if I use a Geocoder method, i.e., geocoded_by or similar, I get a NoMethodError.

I've included the gem in my gemfile (i.e., a line reading 'gem "geocoder"'). I've installed the bundles, too.

Any advice would be appreciated. I'm rather new to Ruby and Rails.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Have you run `bundle install`? It installs all gems in Gemfile.

Answer (score 1):

Add to following line to Gemfile and Run bundle install

```
gem "geocoder"
```

You can refer [Railscast-#273](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?view=asciicast), You will get a clear idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `require 'geocoder'` to the top of the ruby file it is used in.